# Flex: repeater item as an array index (binding)

Tags: apache-flex

I have a label inside a repeater (rptInfos), and I have an arraycollection (Texts) that has the translations. The "Texts" content is changing when I change the language, and normally I use {Texts.getItemAt(219}} for example when I need a translated text. But in the repeater I have a translateable column, so I want to use it like this:

```
<s:Label text="{Texts.getItemAt(rptInfos.currentItem.DictID as int)}" />
```

but it says "Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute , not target"
I wanted to translate it in the labels creationComplete event, but than I can forget about binding, so only when reloaded can I have the content to update.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess: try

```
<s:Label text="{Texts.getItemAt(Number(rptInfos.currentItem.DictID))}" />
```

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightparen. [Generated code (use -keep to save): Path: _CC_Components_RequestsWatcherSetupUtil.as, Line: 0, Column: 0] technoWebShop  Unknown Flex Problem

Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error: expecting rightparen before target. [Generated code (use -keep to save): Path: _CC_Components_RequestsWatcherSetupUtil.as, Line: 0, Column: 0] technoWebShop  Unknown Flex Problem

Comment: @SteMa How about just `<s:Label text="{Texts.getItemAt(rptInfos.currentItem.DictID)}" />`

Answer (score 0):

A not so nice, but working solution :S

```
                            <s:Label text="{rptInfos.currentItem.DictID==254?Texts.getItemAt(254):
                                 rptInfos.currentItem.DictID==255?Texts.getItemAt(255):
                                 rptInfos.currentItem.DictID==256?Texts.getItemAt(256):
                                 rptInfos.currentItem.DictID==257?Texts.getItemAt(257):
                                 rptInfos.currentItem.DictID==258?Texts.getItemAt(258):
                                 rptInfos.currentItem.DictID==259?Texts.getItemAt(259):''}" />
```